# Managing scroll state between sibling components in React/Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, architecture, redux, react-redux

How can a React component control the scroll position of a sibling component?

`Parent` is the parent component, it has as children `List` (which contains a scrollable div) and `Actions` with a button that should control scrolling of the `List` scrollable div.

Some options:

1. Maintain a reference to the DOM element of the scrollable div and scroll position in the Redux Store. Trigger scrolling in the reducer on state changes.
2. Have `Parent` manage scroll. Somehow `Parent` needs to have a DOM reference to the scrollable div in `List`, not sure how `List` can pass up a ref.
3. Use something like [react virtualized](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/) (`VirtualScroll`) to show virtual content in `List`. Don't actually scroll, just update the content to what would be seen at the new scroll position. This means we can't animate the scroll?

Option #2 seems most reasonable (animated scroll is important for this context), but I'm not sufficiently familiar with best practices in React/Redux to make good architecture decisions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for option 2. But the parent should not have to keep a reference to the List items other than having them as child components. You can save the the scroll position in the redux store, have the parent control it, and then pass it down as a prop to your List items.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import List from './List';

class Parent extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
        dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        scrollPos: PropTypes.number.isRequired
    };

    updateScrollPos() {
        const value = getValueFromSomewhere();
        this.dispatch({ type: UPDATE_SCROLLPOS, value })
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            <button onClick={::this.updateScrollPos}>Update scrollPos</button>
            <List scrollPos={this.props.scrollPos} />
            <List scrollPos={this.props.scrollPos} />
            <List scrollPos={this.props.scrollPos} />
        </div>
    }
}


const select = (state) => ({
    scrollPos: state.scrollPos
})

export default connect(select)(Parent);
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Quite simple. Thank you!